# Better constructed pagination

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I've dynamically created a simple pagination for my article collection. The problem is that on select ALL option  there are over more than 200 articles, its coded that there are 8 articles per page. Now I have this large line of 28 pagination button which is an overkill. Could I shrink the line with fixed width and then use the **overflow:scroll** ? Are there any better solutions that I don't know of?

this is what I've done so far. Now the first four and the last four are displayed :

```
var div = document.getElementById('pagination-filtered');
                var numOfPage = 1;
                var filterLength = Math.ceil(novostiObjFiltered.length / numPerPage);
            
                console.log(filterLength);
                for (var i = 0; i < filterLength; i++) {
                    var tempdisplay = 'none';
                    if (i < 4 || i > filterLength-5) {
                        tempdisplay = 'block';
                    }
                    var btn = document.createElement('button');
                    var txt = document.createTextNode(String(numOfPage));
                    btn.appendChild(txt);
                    btn.setAttribute('type', 'button');
                    btn.setAttribute('value', numOfPage);
                    btn.setAttribute('id', 'button' + numOfPage);
                    btn.setAttribute('class', 'pagination_buttons');
                    btn.setAttribute('style', 'display:'+tempdisplay+';');
                    div.appendChild(btn);
                    numOfPage++;

                }
```

[image]

Comment: Actually you should consider showing `...` in middle

Comment: I did that now by using the  jQuery after(). But the functionality of those . . . is giving me problems. Beacuse the number of pagination buttons is never the same, on the first page where 'ALL' is selected there are 28 buttons, on other filter there are 19 buttons etc.

Comment: This question sort of straddles the line between [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [the User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)...

Comment: Well from the UX/UI its definetly better to shrink the pagination. But for the functionality I think I can get most help here on Stack Overflow. If I get any 

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Pagination.js jQuery Plugin](https://pagination.js.org/) to easily customize how you want your Pagination to be dynamically displayed.

For example:

```
$('#demo').pagination({
    dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 195],
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        // template method of yourself
        var html = template(data);
        dataContainer.html(html);
    }
})
```

Will display as:

[image]

Comment: I was using this plugin on the pagination before that, I have to filter my articles and the other pagination is already in use before that. after the items are filtered I create my own pagination. It works fine, just the number of buttons is the problem